# How to create custom form date validation error messages in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Using Symfony 4, I have a form with a date field. Safari (MacOS) and I.E. do not support HTML5 date pickers. When a user submits a date (without using a date picker), I want the error message to read "Please format your date yyyy-mm-dd" instead of the default "This value is not valid."

Here is my form class:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date', DateType::class, [
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => MyEntity::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my entity class:

```
class MyEntity
{
   /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    private $date;

    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Date(
 *      message="Please format your date yyyy-mm-dd."
 * )
 */
private $date;
```

I can customize the error messages for TextType form fields, but cannot find any examples for DateType. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have to do is just set `invalid_message` parameter on your field as stated in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#invalid-message)

> invalid_message
>
> type: string default: This value is not valid
>
> This is the validation error message that's used if the data entered
>   into this field doesn't make sense (i.e. fails validation).

which would be something like

```
$builder
        ->add('date', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'invalid_message' => 'Please format your date yyyy-mm-dd'
        ])
    ;
```